# C: If source IP header change, TCP header checksum also change

Tags: c, tcp, ip, checksum

is there partial/incremental method to get the new TCP checksum without recalculating everything ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Just google "Incremental TCP checksum" and you'll find lots of data.

The basic idea is to add the difference between the old and new IPs to the old checksum.
But the arithmetic should be 1's complement, which complicates things a bit.